# Java - best practices for secure session management

Tags: java, security, session

I'm trying to write Rest APIs which performs user login, logout. And I want session information to persist (used to Redis to store session information).

I'm new to Java and web development. Need help in understanding:

1. What is the most industry's best practices to create & maintain sessions? Like how e-commerce sites handle sessions?
2. How they ensure sessions are secured? Did lot of search but didn't find any satisfactory answer to this. Are there any ready made Java implementations used in industry that I can look for?
3. Currently using UUID as sessionID. Is there any best practice guide for the same?

Answer (score 2):

Try [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/). It is very useful in the context of Java. It offers a rich set of functionalities including session handling, cryptography, etc.